# How to select the parameter coming from script output and pass it to next script or job in Bamboo?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, bamboo

I am trying to do below things in bamboo.I have script which basically shows the branches of hg repository.I know there is a plugin in Jenkins where you can run the script and get the output and use that output as a parameter to the job/script but I am not sure how to achieve this in Bamboo.Is there any plugin or some way to achieve this?

script abc.py which gives the below output

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

I want this script will run and it will give me the above output and then I can select anyone of them and pass it to my script.The value of the createBranch should come from the script so I can select any one of them

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Bamboo, it is impossible to create/change a variable value from within tasks due to concurrency issues it might create. There is a [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10272) open for this.

As a workaround, how about writing the script result out to a text file, then read it in from the file using [Inject Variables plugin task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+a+variables+task). You can use this as a variable within the same stage to create a branch in your case.

Hope that helps.